# Can't pass a SortedDictionary to a WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, dictionary, static

This is a quick code of my a my `asmx` WebService method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test(SortedDictionary<string, string> signature_additional_parameters)
{
    return "empty";
}
```

but it says this:

*The type System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23523TEASDV],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23523TEASDV]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.*

It works if I set the method `static`, but at that point I can't call the method via WebService.

How can I fix this trouble?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary(IDictionary) is not serializable. An easy workaround is to have a List that has a class containing a Key and Value class and making sure the key is unique.

Comment: But if I need this class, I need to define it also on the Client caller. That's decentralize the whole system.

Comment: @markzzz Not really. Just as with wcf it makes a copy of the data contract on the client side. Its just defining the way you exchange data. If that is really an issue you can use a string of the format {0};{1} and then split it but I would not do that.